# How do I draw a line in java using points?

Tags: java, arraylist

I was wondering how I'd use different points in Java to draw a line. Here is the code I have so far. I would prefer to not get the x and y of each point and just have the program use the points from x, y on its own. I am still pretty new to programming and not very good at using javadoc at this point. The following is the code I have now:

```
 //Create a Polygon class. A polygon is a closed shape with lines joining the corner points. 
 //You will keep the points in an array list. Use object of java.awt.Point for the point.

 //Polygon will have as an instance variable an ArrayList of Points to hold the points
 //The constructor takes no parameters but initializes the instance variable.  The
 //Polygon class also has the following methods:
 //    add: adds a Point to the polygon
 //    perimeter: returns the perimeter of the polygon
 //    draw: draws the polygon by connecting consecutive points and then
 //          connecting the last point to the first.
 //
 //No methods headers or javadoc is provided this time. You get to try your hand at writing
 //a class almost from scratch

 // Need help starting this question? In the lesson titled
 // "Starting points: Problem Set Questions", go to the
 // problem titled "Problem Set 6 - Question 3" for some tips on 
 // how to begin.

 import java.util.ArrayList; import java.awt.Point;

 public class Polygon {
     ArrayList<Point> points;

     /**
     **  a Polygon represents a shape with flat lines and several points.
     */ 
     public Polygon(){
     /**
     * Constructs empty array of points.
     */
     points = new ArrayList<Point>();
     }    /**    ** Adds points to the polygon points Array.    *@param = points x and y coordinates to add to class    */
     public void addPoints(Point point){
         points.add(point);
     }
     /**
     **gets distance between points in ArrayList
     */
     public double perimeter(){
         double perimeter = 0;
         int i = 0;
         while(i<points.size()){
             if(i<points.size()-1){
              perimeter = perimeter + points.get(i).distance(points.get(i+1));   
             }
             else{
              perimeter = perimeter + points.get(i).distance(points.get(0));   
             }
         }
         return perimeter;
     }
      /**    * Draws Polygon using points from points ArrayList    */
     public void drawPolygon(){
      int i = 0;
         while(i < points.size()-1){
           Line2D line = Line2D.Float(points.get(i), points.get(i+1));
             line.draw();
         }
         Line2D lastLine = Line2D.Float(points.get(0), points.get(points.size()-1));
         lastLine.draw();
     } }
```

Comment: I guess you want to use the Graphics2D API for your drawings. This tutorial might help you: http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/basicdrawing/

Comment: All that for one line only? There isn't anything simpler? I'm only one month in to learning java, but with graphics library in my course all you need to do is plug in x and y for each point and call .draw() and you're good to go so this seems like it is counter intuitive if my goal was to just plug in the specific point (although I know in real life I probably won't have the course's graphics library which is why I was trying to go this route).

Comment: Actually, real-world java programs do not simply draw a line, but they first create a window with a canvas and draw the line there. It's a bit of an overhead, but the second line is just one method call way. BTW, Graphics2D has a method for drawing polygons: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon(int[],%20int[],%20int)

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand this correctly, you want to implement the `draw()` method?

If so, what you need to do is search for **Bresenham's Algorithm** which draws a line based on two given points.

Comment: I looked it up as per your suggestion. However, everything that comes up seems much more complicated than it should be (and much more complicated than the level I am at in programming at the moment (only one month in). There isn't a simpler method? I found a video series that takes almost an hour to explain it and a bible size website. Both were full of equations and whatnot. Shouldn't it be simpler to draw a line from point a to b?

Comment: @TalC, it is (or should be!). All you should need to do is convert the pseudocode given in one of those links - the arguments to `plot()` command are your points on the line, the remaining mathematics around makes sure that a line is iterated between those two points. The algorithm has to cope with lines in all orientations which is why maybe it looks complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this exact question, because I encountered some MAJOR issues with it too.. I stumbled across this question during Udacity's Java Basics course.

I was so stuck, until I moved onto the proceeding lessons which go onto explain more about classes. I downloaded the Problem Set 6 zip file from https://www.udacity.com/wiki/cs046/code and navigated to the Polygon Project folder. In there, I opened the BlueJay project file and could see all the other classes available for use in my Polygon class.

Once I had initialised a Line in my Polygon draw method, the connection between the Polygon class & the Line class appeared (HOORAY).

You can open the Line class to see what its constructors & methods are. Obviously the Line class is working in with a few other classes to actually be able to draw the line, but we can't see any of this in the Udacity IDE and the question doesn't really tell us either..

Nonetheless, I have added my code, that worked in the Udacity IDE to get the correct output.

I see you have used a distance method on the Point class. I don't think this exists.. Hence the garbage in the middle of my code. I probably could have condensed this somehow, but I was just happy to get the right outputs.

```js
public class Polygon
{
    private ArrayList<Point> shape; //instance variable
    
    public Polygon() //constructs a new ArrayList of points called shape
    {
        shape = new ArrayList<Point>(); 
    }
    
    public void add(Point point) //takes in a Point and adds it to the ArrayList "shape"
    {
        shape.add(point); 
    }
    
    public double perimeter()
    {   
        double total = 0;
        if (shape.size() > 2) //a polygon must have more than 2 sides
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < shape.size() - 1; i++) //for every point in the list, except for the last
            {
                double x1 = shape.get(i).getX();
                double y1 = shape.get(i).getY();
                double x2 = shape.get(i + 1).getX();
                double y2 = shape.get(i + 1).getY();
                double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) //get the distance between the point
                                        + Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2)));     //and the following point
                total = total + dist; //add this distance to the total
            }
            double firstX = shape.get(0).getX();
            double firstY = shape.get(0).getY();
            double lastX = shape.get(shape.size() - 1).getX();
            double lastY = shape.get(shape.size() - 1).getY();
            double finalDist = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(Math.pow((lastX - firstX), 2) //get the distance between 
                                        + Math.pow((lastY - firstY), 2)));      //the first & last points
            total = total + finalDist; //add it to the total
        }
        return total;
    }
    
    public void draw()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < shape.size() - 1; i++) //for every point in the list, except for the last
        {
            double x1 = shape.get(i).getX();
            double y1 = shape.get(i).getY();
            double x2 = shape.get(i + 1).getX();
            double y2 = shape.get(i + 1).getY();
            Line line = new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2); //create a new Line "line"
            line.draw(); //draw the line
        }
        double firstX = shape.get(0).getX();
        double firstY = shape.get(0).getY();
        double lastX = shape.get(shape.size() - 1).getX();
        double lastY = shape.get(shape.size() - 1).getY();
        Line lastLine = new Line(lastX, lastY, firstX, firstY); //get the first & last points & create a line
        lastLine.draw(); //draw this line too
    }
}
```